# Getting all elements of a bash array except the first

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an indexed bash array and I'd like to use an expression like "${a[@]}" except I want it to not include a[0].  The best that I can think of is this:

```
j=0
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
    b[j]=${a[++j]}
done
```

and then use "${b[@]}".  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
$ a=(1 2 3)
$ echo "${a[@]:1}"
2 3
```

Comment: think he need that to access the array b. b=(${a[@]:1})

Comment: Yes, that works!  Would you happen to know where in the bash manual that is described?

Comment: They're in the **Arrays** and **Parameter Expansion** sections. That they can be used together is not explicitly mentioned, but it does work.

Comment: Thx, I found it under Parameter Expansion for ${parameter:offset} which says … If parameter is ‘@’, the result is length positional parameters beginning at offset. If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by ‘@’ or ‘*’, the result is the length members of the array beginning with ${parameter[offset]}.

Answer (score 10):

If it's a standard array, use:

```
"${a[@]:1}"
```

If you're working with parameters:

```
"${@:2}"
```

Note the different syntax and that `$@` is 1-indexed (since $0 is the name of the script).